# Why water is coming up out of my toilet when the water is off and the tank is empty

Tags: plumbing

I've got the water turned off to the tank on my toilet and its not filling up but water is coming up out of my toilet but my tank is empty

Comment: There are 2 possible water sources to a toilet. #1 utility supply water going through the tank through the usual valves.  #2 sewer water backing up into the toilet bowl.  To which are you referring?  Supply water fills the tank, sewer water fills the bowl.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another toilet or drain line before this one that supplies the water.

It will fill up with water, but blocked by a clod, so no way to go but out of your toilet.

Snake it to remove the clog.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and let you know how it goes

Comment: @Anthony I really do not need to know what you snaked out :)